# Alguien podria darme un ejemplo de webview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Alguien me podría dar un ejemplo de una webview en xamarin o algun tutorial??
No encuentro ningun ejemplo o tutorial en la web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la [documentacion](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/webview/) puedes encontrar un ejemplo:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithWebview/

Por ejemplo:

Desplegar una pagina web:

```
var browser = new WebView {
    Source = "http://xamarin.com"
};
```

Desplegar un String html:

```
var browser = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource ();
htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
    <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
    <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
    </body></html>";
browser.Source = htmlSource;
```

Recuerda habilitar el permiso INTERNET dentro del AndroidManifest.xml para que el WebView pueda accesar a internet.

Comment: Es para IOS quiero hacer el webview de una pagina. quiero hacer una prueba con la pagina de google.

Comment: Ok Alcides, deberias especificar, pero puedes entrar al link de la documentación y encontraras un link especifico para iOS ahora edito mi respuesta